# tab host and items size for different resolutions

Tags: android, size, android-tabhost

i am developing an app with a tabHost, its working fine,

my question is :

what should be the size for the tab bar background image [width, height], and the tab item background image for all the drawables:

- drawable-hdpi
- drawable-ldpi
- drawable-mdpi

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Android official guide to support multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

[Android Icon Design Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html) will help you to understand the sizes of different sizes of icons.

Here is a nice tool [Android Asset Studio](http://tools.android.com/recent/assetstudiointegration), it'll help you creating icon for all type of sizes.

[This](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_tab.html) is actually the answer to your question. :) Cheers